# Slope floor to create tension in wood

Tags: flooring

My house sits on 42 wood posts. I adjusted at each post to induce a 1/4 % slope (1/4" per 96") for tension 12 years ago. Cold winters cause movements...cracks walls (fixable).
External posts that heave have Styrofoam buried around them to resist frost penetrating down. Internal crawl space heated.
Q: what is best slope to adjust posts now (flat not an option)?

Comment: Can you explain us why flat is not option for you? Because houses should be horizontal and vertical, making a sloped house creates many problems in everyday life. Are you trying to solve some problem this way? If so, tell us which so we can find better solution, or is this just a consequence?

Answer (score 5):

Flat is an option.

I'm not altogether clear on what scheme you think you were following, or what you think it was doing for you, but it sounds suspiciously like something someone dreamed up and presented as fact, with a dubious or non-existant basis in reality. A slope does not "create tension." A load does that.

Buildings on post foundations are made with level floors all the time. If the posts are set properly, the buildings don't "move and crack" either. If your posts are heaving, they were not set properly...